# Locking Excel Sheets that have ActiveX Checkboxes

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox, locking

I have an excel file that uses multiple ActiveX Checkboxes, of course these all have a linked cell and when clicked pulls data from another sheet to show a figure next to the checkbox.

The file also uses concatenation to provide information once a person has chosen from some data validation drop downs above - The concatenation occurs on the sheets elsewhere so of course many cells change values depending on selection of the drop downs and check boxes.

Is there a way of locking the sheet or workbook that means a person can still choose desired information in the drop downs, for it to concatenate and display information in other cells, and for check boxes to check and show information whilst the user is unable to view and/or select/change any formulas or cells in the sheet?

Hope this is clear, thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Select all the dropdown menus (unless they are Combo Boxes, then you don't need this step), right click and select `Format Cells`, go to tab `Protection`, untick box `Locked`, click `OK`.

Then right click on the sheet tab, select `Protect Sheet...`, unselect box `Select locked cells` and `Select unlocked cells`, scroll down to the very bottom and select "Edit objects", choose a password and click `OK`.

I hope that is what you are searching for.